# Хранение двух value

Tags: jquery, html

Например, мне нужно в поле input radio хранить сразу два значения (два value). Не спрашивайте зачем, создать два radio не получится. (в общем нужно в полу radio хранить именно два значения).
Я буду обрабатывать это поле через jQuery. Может есть какой нибудь атрибут, в котором можно было бы хранить значение?

```
<input type="radio" id="mai" value="Значение 1" `Еще атрибут для значения`="Значения 2">
```

Это полу будет обрабатываться через jQuery.

Comment: jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)? нет, не то? и к нему в добавок [HTML 5 data- Attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Comment: Тоесть я могу сам назначить имя атрибута и хранить в нём информацию?
Например:
<input type="radio" id="mai" value="Значение 1" ="Значения 2">

Comment: @Spectre мне кажется что ТСу явно не нужны такие "сложности" =)

Comment: Всё понял. Большое всем спасибо за помощь!!!

Answer (score 1):

для этих целей можно использовать любой атрибут, но реккомендуется использовать data атрибуты, готовимся к html 5
[custom data attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="mai" value="Значение 1" ololo="Значения 2">
```

---

```
// достать, как, собственно, и переписать, можно так
$("#mai").attr( 'ololo' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Да любой аттрибут и храните.
Например

```
<input type="radio" id="mai" value="Значение 1" attr1="Значения 2">
```

А вытягивайте

```
$("#mai").attr("attr1");
```

Comment: на пару секунд опоздал :)